# Calling service() of servlet from another servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a url-mapping in my `web.xml` such that requests for a specific url `x.pt` gets mapped to a Servlet say `Servlet1`. In the `service()` of this servlet I check if the request has some specific parameter.

If so, the call is delegated to another servlet `Servlet2` by instantiating it and calling its service method.

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    // if the call is for some special events (request has some specific parameter)
    if (req.getParameter(conditionCheck()) {
        doPost(req, res);
    } else {
        // Report parsing
    }
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        // instantiate Servlet2 object
        servlet2.init(this.getServletConfig());
        servlet2.service(req, res);
        servlet2.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to execute event", e);
    }
}
```

The browser returns some JSON text when the request is for special events( i.e. to Servlet2)
Do let me know if I need to do something extra for getting response of Servlet2 to the brwoser.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question? Does this work or do you have a problem?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. Why don't you just redirect/forward the request to the second servlet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward your request using RequestDispacher:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destination);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kris says, I'd expect a RequestDispatcher to work, but I'm always uncomfortable when I see a servlet being called directly like this. Do you have the opportunity to move the logic that is provided by servlet2 into a separate object that both servlet1 and servlet2 can call upon? If you can, I think it'll give you a better, more easily testable solution.